# Making website static with zoom in - out

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I think this question is so stupid but forgive me. I'm still learning. 
I've converted my website psd to html, css and it's perfect for my monitor. But when someone runs it on less monitor or bigger, everything mess up. Even when I zoom in / out. The content itself is 1024 and the rest are only background. I want like making everything static and whoever previews the website on bigger monitors, the more expands on the background without changing any place. I see this thing in many websites but I cannot locate it in the ass, don't know where is it or what makes the website so static that when I zoom in - out it only zooms in - out as it should be. Not moving divs and messes up things that shouldn't be moved.

Explaining more easily:
There's some websites when you zoom in - out, the content only gets bigger or smaller but it doesn't move from its actual place. I can't do this thing and I would like to know how it's done. Is there any requires rule in the css to add for each div / class? Anything to insert in the body area? etc.

Sorry if I'm not clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Example of what I want: http://www.exiliumworld.com/
You can zoom in out and the position will still static without changing its place. only gets small or magnified

Comment: We can't help you without seeing some code...